# Google Sheets "Unresolved sheet name" even though sheet exists

Tags: google-sheets

Every time I refresh my Workbook, I get a bunch of "Unresolved sheet name" errors even though the sheet exists.
If i select the cell and hit enter twice the error goes away and the data populates.

Anyone encountered this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Perhaps you could be a little more specific about the where and when the "Unresolved sheet name" errors occur. A snapshot of the error would help understand the context; you could edit your question to include the snapshot. Could could also firm up what you understand "a bunch" means. Is this code related? Then you should edit your question to include the code.

Comment: I've got this same error for sheet that does indeed exist. Would love for someone to try to answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Order of operations matters.

I've run into the "Unresolved sheet name" error previously when copying sheets over into a new spreadsheet.

If `sheet A` refers to `sheet B`, make sure you copy over sheet B first. Otherwise `sheet A` won't be able to find `sheet B`, and even re-writing the formula may not work.

Answer (score 2):

I went in the order prescribed above and still ran into the same error. Ultimately the cells refreshed and calculated by clicking on them and pressing enter. If you highlight the range with multiple errors and keep the enter key held down, it will move through the entire range column by column. Not the best solution but it worked for me.